# Inline CSS background-image not displaying

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to use the CSS background-image property inline in order to display a different background image according to the link used to get to the page, with the remaining properties set in the CSS stylesheet.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="imagecontainer" style="background-image: url('gallery/images/<?php echo $image;?>');">
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.imagecontainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The developer view in my browser shows that the image and CSS file are linked correctly, but nothing is displaying.  Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also add `height` value to `.imagecontainer` class. By default `div` elements have `height = 0` if content or child nodes not provided.

```
.imagecontainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; // or any other value
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you set height to div style for example

```
.imagecontainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when the div is empty the hight is automaticly 0px so to fill it . try this :

```
<body>
    <div class="imagecontainer"
style="background-image: url('gallery/images/<?php echo $image;?>');">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

PS : note the `&nbsp;`
it might help ;)
or give it a fixed  height in the css :

```
height:"yourheight"px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the Div is flat. It has no size on it so it exists but you can't see it because the size of it is 0px X 1000px (for example)

I recommend you adding something inside the Div or just setting the height on the CSS

```
.imagecontainer{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use image as background, its necessary to specify its height (or width base on your application)

```
.imagecontainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;

}
```

if You want to set your background base on your image size:

```
div {
    background-image:url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
}
```

its because of repeat feature of background property, when you use just a div with no other element inside it, div will have height equal zero, To find out what I mean, change your code to:

```
<body>
    <div class="imagecontainer" style="background-image: url('gallery/images/<?php echo $image;?>');">
         Test
    </div>
</body>
```

In this code, your div height will equal to your `test` font size plus its margin and padding.